# UITableView.reloadRows resets row animation type when gets called inside Timer.scheduledTimer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm looking for delayed row animation with `RowAnimation` type **'bottom'** and with specific duration for pushing rows to table view.

So far I found two options:

1. Call `UITableView.reloadRows` inside `UIView.transition` to set animation duration, call `UIView.transition` inside `Timer.scheduledTimer` to set the delay:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { _ in
    UIView.transition(with: self.tableView,
                      duration: 1.0,
                      animations: {
                          self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .bottom)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

**This way animation duration is OK, but `RowAnimation` type is reset (from '.bottom' I suppose to '.automatic').**

2. Use `CATransaction` for animation with duration, and call it inside `Timer.scheduledTimer` to set the delay:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { _ in
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1)

    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .bottom)

    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

**This way `RowAnimation` type is OK, but animation duration is not respected.**

How to set up properly either the `RowAnimation` type not to be reset or the animation duration for `CATransaction` with delay?

Answer (score 0):

Use `main` `DispatchQueue's`, **`asyncAfter(deadline:,qos:,flags:,execute)`** method like so,

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {[weak self] in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self?.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .bottom)
    })
}
```

Add whatever delay you want as per your requirement. I used 1.0 second here.

Comment: Tried it already, same result as with timer (also note you didn't take into account animation duration).

Comment: @peter This approach has the issue mentioned in question title - ```RowAnimation``` is reset, and the cell is animated with fade + some controls movements, so I believe it's **'.automatic'**.